# Add encrypted shared folder on synology key manager manually through SSH

Tags: synology

I ran into a problem with my key manager on synology ds1520+. My key manager seems to have reset itself sometime a few months back. Not sure how or why this has happened, but I am looking to see if it is possible to edit the ecryptfs config file or other sort of file to manually add my encrypted shared folder back into my key manager. I have forgotten the passphrase to the encrypted folder, but I do still have the old @keystore file that is meant to unlock my shared folder when in the key manager. Is there a way to add my @keystore encrypted key file to the key manager without using the keymanager itself to unlock my shared folder? Or is there a way to figure out my passphrase from the @keystore file?

Thanks

Comment: Hello... Anyone able to help me?